# Minifig head with orange glasses - Which set is it from?

Tags: set-identification

I am trying to make a LEGO minifig self-portrait, and I found a head that looks similar enough.

But I can't for the life of me figure out which set this is from.  Do you know?

[image: Orange glasses]

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb0469#T=C&C=3

I am aware I can buy the head in isolation, I am just curious if anyone knows the set it comes from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is likely from the [Skier](https://rebrickable.com/sets/8684-12/skier/) in CMF Series 2:

[image: Skier photo]

TLG has used a number of different head molds at different times. The head that you linked to is the hollow stud mold, whereas the one listed in the inventory for the set uses the blocked open stud mold. My guess is that a small number of these sets used the [blocked open stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626bpb0469) mold, and that's how there are a few of these floating around.

If you're curious, these are the main mold variations:

[image: Minifig head mold variations]

Comment: Awesome find, thank you so much!